# Why is my Rails app not loading using Passenger 3, RVM and Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I am having difficulties with Passenger 3, Apache, RVM and a Rails 3.1 application on Ubuntu. For some reason, the Rails app is not loading, however I have run basically the same configuration before and had no problem.

I have Ruby 1.9.2 installed in RVM and Passenger installed with all gems in default.

I put the following in the `apache.conf` file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

This is my virtual hosts configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server
  DocumentRoot /root/www/tester/public
  <Directory /root/www/tester/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Passenger appears to be loading, as the Apache log shows:

```
[Wed Jan 11 23:18:28 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

but, I cannot get the application to load at all.

If I run Passenger standalone I get the following error:

```
2012/01/11 23:03:31 [error] 13427#0: *4 "/root/www/sound/public/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
```

I changed all the permissions to `755` and gave ownership to `apache (www-data)` but to no avail.

Finally, when I run passenger-status, I get:

```
----------- General information -----------
  max      = 6
  count    = 0
  active   = 0
  inactive = 0
 Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
```

But, as you can see, there is no application loaded.

Answer (score 3):

FIXED! - I needed to delete the default virtual hosts file in sites-enabled directory!

Comment: This was the issue for me as well!

Comment: Where is this sites-enabled directory? / Edit it is in /etc/apache2 on Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're looking in the right place,
and its something to do with user permissions.

Number 1 rule for Passenger is;

- Passenger will run as the user which owns "config/environment.rb" (or "config.ru" for rack apps)

Also, I'd suggest, don't ever run as root.

`/var/www` or `/var/rails` are common places to put your rails apps

but I usually end up having a user for each app, and putting it in the home directory.

Namely, for my application I have;

1. the user `myapp`
2. the directory `/home/myapp/deploy/`
3. a symlink to the code at `/home/myapp/deploy/current`
4. all these directories are owned by `myapp`

My apache config is something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp.com
  DocumentRoot /home/myapp/deploy/current
</VirtualHost>
```

For me this makes the separation of ownership clear,
and avoids any of these problems.

(notably, all tasks done via capistrano are done as the `myapp` user)

Comment: actually.. looking at it again, your error is for `/root/www/sound/public/index.html` ... is this a different virtual host?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply.  I put the application in /var/www and it is now being listed by apache2 (as expected) but not served by passenger.  Dude, I really appreciate the help, it is annoying as I am unable to even debug it.

Comment: I have also change the permissions to root sudo chmod -R 755 sound and sudo chown -R root:root sound and then restarted apache as root but again with no luck.

Comment: FIXED! - I needed to delete the default virtual hosts file in sites-enabled directory!